# Simple "quick & dirty" stats for C++ containers/ranges

Tags: gratis, open-source, library, software-development, c++

I'm looking for a small header-only library which takes a C++ container (or range, or iterator pair) with numbers, and gives you some basic stats about it: average, variation, kurtosis, standard deviation, standard error, order statistics (e.g. quartiles and deciles), mode, support set cardinality - these sorts of things.

This is of course not difficult to write yourself (and a bit of it is in the standard library anyway); so somebody must have written something like up nicely.

Requirements:

- Header-only
- Modern C++'ish, i.e. no weird virtual stuff, macro-based metaprogramming etc.
- Non-restrictive license: 3-BSD, ASL, MIT or such
- Maintained
- Gratis
- Platform-independent

Desired:

- Single header file

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of [Boost.Accumulators](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/accumulators.html) by Eric Niebler, but while it itself is header only, it has a lot of Boost dependencies which might be a bit heavyweight for your use-case. Especially I'm not sure if Boost is "Modern C++'ish" enough for you as it was originally written pre-C++11.

One pro is certainly that it allows to calculate multiple of these stats in one go.